# Assign an array at a specific memory address in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Let say I have an array of numbers

```
.DATA
    number DB   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80
```

How can I assign the starting point of this array at memory address 100h?

Answer (score 1):

If you need your array `number` reside at **linear address 00100h**, you would have to copy it there at run-time:

```
SUB AX,AX
MOV ES,AX  
MOV DI,100h   ; Let ES:DI point at the linear address 100h.    
MOV AX,.DATA
MOV DS,AX     
MOV SI,number ; Let DS:SI point at the array. 
MOV CX,80     ; Size of the array. 
CLD
REP MOVSB     ; Copy the array to the linear address 100h.
```

This is not a good idea, the first 1024 bytes of linear address space is reserved for interrupt vectors, you would overwrite addresses of `INT 40h` and higher, see [DOS memory map](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/94-general_memory_map.html)

You probably want your array reside at **offset 100h** from the beginning of segment `.DATA`. Fill the first 256 bytes in this segment with anything this long, for instance `

```
 .DATA
        DB 100h DUP (0)
 number DB 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80
```